# glfwCreateWindow() doesnt work out of DLL`s EntryPoint

Tags: c++, dll, glfw

I have .dll file with my Game Engine and .exe with game.
.exe uses .dll

Both of them use glfw_mt.lib.
In dll There is Window class (Window.cpp,Window.h) where i try to glfwCreateWindow(), but it returns NULL. **HOWEVER** when i try it in dlls main function (EntryPoint.h) glfwCreateWindow() works fine.

My Window abstractionm fails to create glfw window. I see no reason
EntryPoint.h in dll

```
#include "Core.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#ifdef NK_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

#define NIKSON_START Nikson::Game* CreateGame(){return
#define NIKSON_END }
extern NIKSON_API Nikson::Game* CreateGame();
static void callback(int error_code, const char* description) {
    std::cout << "GLFW ERROR:" << error_code << " " << description << std::endl;
}
int main() 
{
    LOG("LOADED!");glfwSetErrorCallback(callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        LOG("GLFW ERROR");
    }
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
    //GLFWwindow* win = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 1000, "Nikson", NULL, NULL);

    //  LOG(win)
    //
    ///*if (win==nullptr) {
    //  LOG("FAILED TO CREATE WINDOW")
    //  return 0;
    //}*/
    //glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    Nikson::Window* win = Nikson::CreateWindow("Nikson",1000,1000);
    std::cin.get();
    //Nikson::Game * game= CreateGame();
    ////Nikson::Window* win = new Nikson::Window();
    //game->Run();
    delete win;
}
#endif
```

Window.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Core.h"
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

namespace Nikson {
    struct WindowProp {
        std::string Title;
        uint32_t Width;
        uint32_t Height;
        GLFWwindow* WindowPtr;
    };
    
    class NIKSON_API Window
    {
    public:
        Window(GLFWwindow* window, const std::string& title = "Nikson",
            uint32_t width = 1600,
            uint32_t height = 900);
        void Tick();
    private:
        WindowProp m_Properities;
        
        
    };
    NIKSON_API Nikson::Window*  CreateWindow(const std::string& title = "Nikson",
        uint32_t width = 1600,
        uint32_t height = 900);
}
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"

namespace Nikson
{
    
    Window::Window(GLFWwindow* window, const std::string& title,
        uint32_t width,
        uint32_t height)
    {
        m_Properities.Title = title;
        m_Properities.Width=width;
        m_Properities.Height=height;
        m_Properities.WindowPtr = window;
        
    }
    void Window::Tick() {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    Nikson::Window* CreateWindow(const std::string& title,
        uint32_t width,
        uint32_t height) 
    {
        GLFWwindow* win = glfwCreateWindow(1000,1000,"Nikson", NULL, NULL);
        if (win == NULL) {
            LOG(win)
        }
        /*if (win==nullptr) {
            LOG("FAILED TO CREATE WINDOW")
            return 0;
        }*/
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
        return new Nikson::Window(win, title, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work when you also call `glfwInit()` from inside `CreateWindow`?

Comment: Your description contradicts your question title, does it work or does it not? Also, make sure you read the MSDN concerning limitations in the DLLMain function. You simply can't do everything there.

Comment: @BDL  I added glfwInit() in CreateWindow, but it still returns null

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt glfwCreateWindow() only works in dlls main, but not other files in the dll. But i need to be able to do it in Windows class

Comment: DLLs don't usually have a `main()` function, so I'm not sure what you are referring to and I refuse to guess. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] or at least strip all code not necessary to demonstrate the issue.